# Teradata - Error 2646 Optimization query

Tags: sql, optimization, teradata

Thanks for your answering !

This is an edit :

```
SELECT 'SYSA', 
   t1.lieu_stkph_cd, 
   Sum (t1.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep), 
   Sum (t2.mt_util_dev_rep) 
FROM   (SELECT a.id_auto, a.dt_art, c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
           a.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep 
    FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                   ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                      AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                      AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
    WHERE  c.pma_cd = '') AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id_auto, a.dt_art, c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
           b.mt_util_dev_rep 
    FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                   ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                      AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                      AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_utilisation_a b 
                      ON a.dt_art = b.dt_art 
                      AND a.id_auto = b.id_auto 
    WHERE  c.pma_cd = '') AS t2 
             ON  T1.id_auto = t2.id_auto 
            and T1.dt_art = T2.dt_art and t1.lieu_stkph_cd = t2.lieu_stkph_cd
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2
```

This is the outcome of this query:

LIEU_STKPH_CD       PNU Amount        UTILIZATION AMOUNT 
1                                  200 €
                         250 €

It's not accurate, I explain:

db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a is linked to db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_utilisation_a with
- ID_AUTO 
- DT_ART 
but I can have 1 ID_AUTO for X UTILISATION, so with this query I will multiply by X utilisation the PNU amount, which is not correct

Authorization table

ID_AUTO       PNU amount 
1                                  100 €

Utilization table 
ID_AUTO       ID_UTLIZATION        UTILIZATION AMOUNT 
1                     1
                                100 € 
1                     2
                                150 €

So I have to separate those value:

Expected outcome 
LIEU_STKPH_CD       PNU Amount        UTILIZATION AMOUNT 
1                                  100 €
                         250 €

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance
Christophe

Comment: `2646 no more spool space` is an error?

Comment: It isn't so much a need to optimize the query when you run out of spool. It just means that your interim result sets where Teradata is staging data to be queried again down stream to complete the plan has run out for your user. This can happen when you are dealing with very large data, when you accidently cause cross join, or when your user/profile has a small amount of spool allowance.  In your case you are joining T1 and T2 but you don't provide an ON clause causing a [cartesian product](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm). What is the relationship between T1 and T2?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get rid of the multiplied values, e.g. aggregating before the join

```
SELECT 'SYSA', 
   t1.lieu_stkph_cd, 
   t1.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep, 
   t2.mt_util_dev_rep 
FROM   (SELECT a.id_auto, a.dt_art, c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
           a.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep 
    FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                   ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                      AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                      AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
    WHERE  c.pma_cd = '') AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id_auto, a.dt_art, c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
           Sum(b.mt_util_dev_rep) AS mt_util_dev_rep 
    FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                   ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                      AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                      AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
           INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_utilisation_a b 
                      ON a.dt_art = b.dt_art 
                      AND a.id_auto = b.id_auto 
    WHERE  c.pma_cd = ''
    GROUP  BY 1, 
          2          ) AS t2 
             ON  T1.id_auto = t2.id_auto 
            AND T1.dt_art = T2.dt_art AND t1.lieu_stkph_cd = t2.lieu_stkph_cd
```

But it seems that you don't need to join two Derived Tables, this should return the same result:

```
SELECT 'SYSA', 
   t1.lieu_stkph_cd, 
   -- this value is multiplied by the number of rows 
   -- so simply divide by that number to revert the multiplication 
   Sum (a.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep) / Count(*), 
   Sum (b.mt_util_dev_rep) 
FROM prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
  ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_utilisation_a b 
  ON a.dt_art = b.dt_art 
 AND a.id_auto = b.id_auto 
WHERE  c.pma_cd = ''
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter :) I choose your first solution. However I get a new error 2616 "Numeric overflow occured during compilation". I have supposed I have to cast the numeric value ? Thanks !

Comment: @Christophe: Probably, check the source datatypes (DECIMAL?) and increase precision to 38 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a big guess here on the relationship of your data. You should be joining using an actual `JOIN` clause with an `ON` to explain how these two subqueries are to be brought together. Something like:

```
SELECT 'SYSA', 
       t1.lieu_stkph_cd, 
       Sum (t1.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep), 
       Sum (t2.mt_util_dev_rep) 
FROM   (SELECT c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
               a.mt_pnu_cpta_dev_rep 
        FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
               INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                       ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                          AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                          AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
        WHERE  c.pma_cd = '') AS t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT c.lieu_stkph_cd, 
               b.mt_util_dev_rep 
        FROM   prod_v_ec_dossier_a_sysa c 
               INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_autorisation_a a 
                       ON a.id_doss = c.dosscta_no 
                          AND a.cd_prd_cpta = c.prct_no 
                          AND a.cd_entite_cpta = c.entite_cd 
               INNER JOIN db_ftg_srs_prod_v.v_utilisation_a b 
                       ON a.dt_art = b.dt_art 
                          AND a.id_auto = b.id_auto 
        WHERE  c.pma_cd = '') AS t2 
    ON T1.lieu_stkph_cd = t2.lieu_stkph_cd
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2
```

Comment: yes, from the original post it does look like a cartesian product, which will def spool out

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is ok because you do

```
 SELECT ( select ... ) as field 1, 
        ( select ... ) as field 2,
```

But your second you are doing a cross join

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( select ... ) as query1,
      ( select ... ) as query2
```

That create a query with query1 x query2 rows

You want:

```
 SELECT query.*
 FROM ( SELECT ( select ... ) as field1,
               ( select ... ) as field2
        .....
      ) as query
```